# VScode terminal is not working with remote development extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-extensions, remote-development

I have installed remote development extension on vscode.

After successfully connecting to remote server, I can browse the folders and files without any issue. However, I open my vscode terminal and it has no text on it.
I can't type in any command either.

Do you know what's going on?

Here is the screen shot of the vscode terminal that connect to a remote server via remote development extension.

[image: terminal screen shot]